Transaction Error: "Instruction #3 Failed - invalid program argument"
I’m facing an issue while trying to send Solana using the Phantom wallet. The transaction fails, and the Solana explorer shows the following error:
Program Error: "Instruction #3 Failed - invalid program argument"
I’ve tested this with Phantom and another wallet, but the issue persists. The transaction doesn’t go through.
Has anyone encountered this problem before? What could be causing it, and how can I fix it? Any help would be appreciated!

can you share the explorer link to the tx?

https://solscan.io/tx/3TurApAaAzKSNm5wgSUxwCHoXCLhFKoqmAZM8DdzMYy7C1RfEZfTYg5Zcw5CJeo9fmVzMyNL5MfTyv14sS7QdLFT @Jimii

I will share Jon's answer from a previously asked question.
You are trying to call the transfer instruction with the sender being a nonce account. https://explorer.solana.com/address/EWMePbDZvV8wF5mwg5g6XbVnMWySHgVkrRU7AhYJXT9c

If you want to withdraw SOL from a nonce account, you'll need to use the withdraw_nonce_account instruction: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/4c2e79fe159d0d27b732468da3d88225ebe62e32/sdk/program/src/system_instruction.rs#L1663

